# What is this "?." feature called, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Just realized it exists, thanks to VSCode enforcing it...

- I don't know what it is called;
- It's not TypeScript.

**Usage**

```
let regex = /hot/g;
let phrase = "It's hot, outside.";

// you don't need to worry about null
let matches = phrase.match(regex)?.length;
```

Comment: It's the "optional chaining operator", as per https://caniuse.com/#search=%3F.

Comment: As people answered it's called optional chaining, however it's also called elvis operator sometimes.

Comment: @YairCohen Why is it called the "Elvis Operator"?

Comment: "The name "Elvis operator" refers to the fact that when its common notation, ?:, is viewed sideways, it resembles an emoticon of Elvis Presley with his quiff." - Wikipedia

Comment: Optional chaining. I believe it's an ES6 feature.

Comment: @MikeFurlender not es6, rather es2020 (so it's quite new :))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That feature is called [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). This calls the method when the receiver is neither `undefined` nor `null`.

Comment: Commonly combined with the [nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)